# Why does 'mousemove'-event triggers on page load and how to prevent this (using jQuery mobile)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, jquery-events, mousemove

when I bind the mousemove-event on the body

```
$("body").mousemove(function(e)...
```

on document-ready it also triggers when the page is loaded, the mouse is inside the browser window but mouse isn't moved. Why is that? How could I prevent this?

Edit: seems that this is a Safari-Bug. In Firefox I can't reproduce this behaviour.

Comment: this should not be happening. can you show your code on fiddle?

Comment: it doesn't according to http://jsfiddle.net/zUHjn/ Maybe you make a manual `trigger` somewhere that bubbles up to the body ?

Comment: I also did set the bubbles-variable to false to prevent this.

Comment: @headkit, can you post a live example ?

Comment: maybe its because uning jquery mobile...

Comment: can't reproduce on jsfiddle - hm...

Comment: but this only happens, when the mouse is inside the browser window!

Comment: ok, try this link: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/2896178/problem_mousemove.zip

Comment: seems that this is a Safari-Bug. In FF I can't reproduce this behaviour.

Comment: here is a fiddle, too. you need to try this in Safari 6.0.1, please: http://jsfiddle.net/headkit/LcT7f/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**this should not be happining anyhow just try bind() or live().**

```
$("body").stop(true)
$("body").bind('mousemove', function(e){
 alert('mouse moved');
});
```

Answer (score -1):

on load, call the following :-

```
document.onmousemove=return false;
window.onmousemove=return false;
```

MouseDown will not work